# Does exceptions throw inside an One method makes the channel faulted?

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, channel, isoneway

If I set `IsOneWay=true` in a method, does exceptions thrown inside it affect the channel or the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No exception will make it to the client, but it will fault any unreliable channel.
[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx):

> one-way operations can't return values, and any exception thrown on the service side will not make its way to the client.

Any in case you want some more details check out this [blog on codeidle](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Operations/One-Way-Operations/) it will walk you through one way operations, including what happens when an exception is thrown.

As scary as this sounds it is dependent on the binding, I am trying to find the appropriate resource now that explains it: [WCF And One Way Behavioral Inconsistency](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/zuker/archive/2009/01/26/wcf-and-oneway-behavioral-inconsistency.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure `it will fault underlying channel` ?